# How to hide or disable the product price for all the pages in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.2

**I don't want to use any commercial module for hiding price.**

> And i don't want hide by using templates.

Is there any way to hide price from entire site using plugins or rewrites?